# How can I change a column to a column from another dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, conditional-statements

I have this data frame "cus" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPtvb.png) and need to replace column "nationality_code" with respective weight from this dataframe "scores" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNCn7.png).

So "nationality_code" PT form "cus" represents 10 from "scores". I need to replace all rows from "cus". Can anyone help me please?

I'm just doing manually using this

```
cus['nationality_code'].mask(cus['nationality_code'] == 'IE', sco.loc[sco['code'] == "IE", 'risk_weight'].iloc[0], inplace=True)
```

But I need to type this code 100+ times because I have 100+ country codes to replace.

Comment: will be better if you can provide minimal reproducible example. take a few rows from your data and give it as text, csv preferably, so others can just take that data to form answers. also one of your screenshot doesn't mention column names.

Answer (score 0):

You could :

1. merge both dataframes based on their code (`nationality_code` for `cus` and `code` for `sco`). From `sco` you only need to enrich with `risk_weight` column.
2. Then simply replace `nationality_code` from `cus` with imported `risk_weight` from `sco`.
3. Finally remove imported `risk_weight` column if not needed anymore.

This could look like (with `cus_extended` being your new dataframe with `nationality_code` being replaced) :

```py
cus_extended = cus.merge(sco[["code", "risk_weight"]], how="left", left_on="nationality_code", right_on="code")
cus_extended["nationality_code"] = cus_extended["risk_weight"]
cus_extended.drop("risk_weight", axis=1)
```

Disclaimer: This assumes `cus` dataframe does not contain any column named `risk_weight`, and that you do not have duplicate in column `code` from `sco`. Without a reproducible example, it is hard to anticipate edge cases though.